# chef plugin for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

1) As for my requirement i need to install chef plugins in jenkins. could you please provide the installation process.

2) i have installed the chef plugins (.hpi) manually in jenkins but its not reflecting in my dashboard under configuration tab

3) i have downloaded the chef-jenkins plugins in zip format and have renamed the plugin extension as .hpi and moved the file into /var/lib/jenkins/plugins. i have restarted the jenkin service its not reflecting in my dashboard under configuration tab

Comment: What chef plugin do you mean?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to install the chef cookbook for Jenkins, as a plugin to Jenkins.... Doesn't work that way. Chef can be used to install Jenkins master servers and slave nodes. Not aware of a chef plugin for Jenkins. Perhaps you should outline what you're trying to do....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he may mean https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin/, but have not had a chance to check in details.